# Weird behavior of Paho-MQTT python library on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, mqtt, paho

I'm working on a project using paho-mqtt python library. I have two machines Raspberry pi 3 and a desktop with ubuntu 20.04. The Mosquitto broker installed on the Raspberry pi and my python code running on Ubuntu.

The two machines connected over LAN. when I use Mosquitto client CLI on Ubuntu to publish to the broker (broker running on the Raspberry pi) it is working fine but when I use python code it is working once when I run the code for many time it connects once time only. when I run the python code on the Raspberry pi it working fine without any problem.

I installed Mosquitto broker on Ubuntu also faced the same problem the python code not working properly.

I used python 3.8 and 3.5 interpreters and tried all paho-mqtt library versions but still the same problem. It also doesn't fire exceptions or show logs. it shows logs only when it connects. I think the problem is in Ubuntu 20.04. My python code below:
mqtthandeler.py

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from configmanager import ConfigManager


# Retrieve the commands and configurations from the server via MQTT
class Subscriber:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = ConfigManager()
        self.cfg.get_config()
        # Network connection status LEDs indicators
        # MQTT connection flag
        self.connected = False

    def test(self, x, y, z):

        print('new command = ' + str(z))

    def mqtt_connect(self):
        global client


        # Creat instance for MQTT client
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['server id'], 
                 clean_session=False, userdata=None,
                             protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311, transport='tcp')

        # Set the username and password to connect to the MQTT Broker
        client.username_pw_set(username=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['authentication']['username'],
                               password=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['authentication']['password'])

        # callbacks for on connect and disconnect
        client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect
        client.on_message = self.on_message
        client.on_log = self.on_log

        # Connect to the MQTT broker
        try:
            client.connect_async(host=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['hostname'],
                                 port=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['port'],
                                 keepalive=60, bind_address="")
            client.loop_start()
            print('try to connect')

    

        except Exception as e:
            #  If debug true print error message
            print('Unable to connect to MQTT broker \n Error message: ' + e)
            if self.cfg.config_data['DEBUG']:
                print('Unable to connect to MQTT broker \n Error message: ' + e)

            else:
                print('Unable to connect to MQTT broker')

    def on_log(self, client, userdata, level, buff):
        print('log= ' + buff)

    # If connected to the MQTT broker print the results of the connection
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):

        self.connected = True
        # Subscribe to the commands topic to receive commands from the server
        client.subscribe(topic=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['topics']['commands'],
                         qos=self.cfg.config_data['MQTT']['qos'])
        if self.cfg.config_data['DEBUG']:
            print("Connection returned result: " + mqtt.connack_string(rc))

    # If disconnected from MQTT broker print the message and try to reconnect again
    def on_disconnect(self, _client, userdata, rc):
        self.connected = False
        if rc != 0 & self.cfg.config_data['DEBUG']:
            print("Unexpected disconnection.")

    # When Message received from MQTT
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        print("Received message '" + str(message.payload) + "' on topic '"
              + message.topic + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))


'''#================================================================================================================#'''


# Publish data to the MQTT
class Publisher(Subscriber):

    def __init__(self):
        qos_cfg = ConfigManager()
        qos_cfg.get_config()
        self._qos = qos_cfg.config_data['MQTT']['qos']

    # ================================================================================================================#
    def publish(self, _topic, msg):
        client.publish(topic=_topic, payload=msg, qos=self._qos)
        print('Sent')
```

main.py

```
from mqtthandler import Subscriber, Publisher



# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("MDL Server Started")
    # Establish connection to the MQTT broker
    mqtt = Subscriber()
    mqtt.mqtt_connect()
    pub = Publisher()
    for i in range(10):
        pub.publish('prox\\', '2222\\')
```

Mosquitto -v output (when the code connected)

```
1612077624: No will message specified.
1612077624: Sending CONNACK to 2222 (1, 0)
1612077624: Received SUBSCRIBE from 2222
1612077624:     command\ (QoS 1)
1612077624: 2222 1 command\
1612077624: Sending SUBACK to 2222
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m2, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m3, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m3, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m4, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m4, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m5, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m5, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m6, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m6, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m7, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m7, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m8, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m8, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m9, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m9, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m10, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m10, rc0)
1612077624: Received PUBLISH from 2222 (d0, q1, r0, m11, 'prox\', ... (5 bytes))
1612077624: Sending PUBACK to 2222 (m11, rc0)
1612077624: Socket error on client 2222, disconnecting.
```

and sometimes Mosquitto -v shows this output after many tries

```
1612078246: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1612079414: New connection from 192.168.10.2 on port 1883.
```

and sometimes nothing on Mosquitto -v
Also, I ran the code outside the virtualenv (Pycharm virtualenv) but the same behavior
I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting the solution that I found in case of someone faces the same problem.

The solution is to add a 0.1-sec delay after calling "mqtt_connect" function in main.py to give the MQTT code enough time to connect to the broker. I think this issue happens because my machine is fast so the program executes and finishes before the MQTT client gets enough time to connect.

final main.py code:

```
import time
from mqtthandler import Subscriber, Publisher

# Stop
# def exit():
#     print('MDL Server stopped')


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("MDL Server Started")
    # Establish connection to the MQTT broker
    mqtt = Subscriber()
    mqtt.mqtt_connect()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    pub = Publisher()
    for i in range(10):
        pub.publish('prox\\', '2222' + '\\')
```